# Set custom error message in ValidationRules in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have set everything perfectly. If I set some string in ErrorMessage then it shows without error.
[image]

What I want is, I want to set ErrorMessage dynamically/programmatically. something

```
MyValidation.ErrorMessage = "some new message";
username.Update() //something
```

XAML Code

```
<TextBox Margin="5" Name="userName">
   <TextBox.Text>
      <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Tag" Mode="OneWayToSource" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
         <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <local:MyValidation ErrorMessage="Static String" />
         </Binding.ValidationRules>
      </Binding>
   </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

C# Class Code

```
public class MyValidation : ValidationRule {
   public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

   public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) {
      if (ErrorMessage.Length > 0) {
         return new ValidationResult(false, ErrorMessage);
      }
      return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
   }
}
```

Comment: can't you just bind it to a model?

Comment: No clue? cloud you just let me know how to do that? @JonathanAlfaro

Comment: You can't bind it because `ErrorMessage` is not a `DependencyProperty`. And you can't implement one, because you can only derive from a single class and therefore can't additionally derive from `DependencyObject`. But why are you binding `TextBox.Text` to `TextBox.Tag`? And why does the error message has to be dynamic, set by an external source? The  message is usually set by the rule itself, according to the actual validation result. There is nothing dynamic

Comment: @BionicCode thanks, but I really wanted to set error from external source.
is there any other way? any other solution apart from this?

Comment: Anything is possible. If you would try to explain what exactly you are trying to achieve and why, I could offer you an appropriate solution. Maybe you are on the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the `ValidationRule` a name in the XAML markup:

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <local:MyValidation x:Name="val" ErrorMessage="Static String" />
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

...you could set its `ErrorMessage` property directly and then just explicitly update the binding:

```
val.ErrorMessage = "some new message";
userName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty)?.UpdateSource();
```

Comment: Brother you saved me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo?view=netframework-4.8) in your viewmodel. Implement `GetErrors(string)` so it returns different error messages based on your condition. You can even return multiple messages at once and they will be displayed below each other.

Here's a nice [tutorial](https://kmatyaszek.github.io/wpf%20validation/2019/03/13/wpf-validation-using-inotifydataerrorinfo.html), but feel free to implement it on your own. Keep in mind that there's not just one correct approach and the interface gives you a lot of freedom.